# Cómo usar negación en Expresiones Regulares para omitir cadenas exactas dentro de un patrón

Tags: regex, asp

Estoy usando asp clásico en donde tengo una variable que contiene un código HTML tal que así:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http:\\salto1"><img src="imagen1.jpg" />Salto 1</a><li>
  <li><a href="http:\\salto2"><img src="imagen2.jpg" />Salto 2</a><li>
  <li><a href="http:\\salto3"><img src="imagen3.jpg" />Salto 3</a><li>
</ul>
```

Y estoy intentando por todos los medios mediante expresiones regulares tratar de reemplazar el `href` del enlace por el `src` de la imagen, pero no tengo forma alguna de conseguirlo.

Mi idea es, para que no coja un `src` que no le corresponda, encontrar la cadena que empiece en `<a href` y acabe en `</a>` siempre y cuando no haya ningún `</a` ya dentro en ella. De esta forma me aseguro que los posibles patrones que le ponga no coja más código del que deba.

El problema es que en expresiones regulares la negación debe ir dentro de corchetes, anulando en todo momento que sea una negación de una cadena exacta:

```
[^<\\a] --> Viene a ser sólo ver un carácter, que NO SEA "<", que NO SEA "\" o que NO SEA "a"
```

Estoy buscando posibles soluciones u otros enfoques.

Comment: Para hacer pruebas con expresiones regulares, yo utilizo la pagina [rubular.com](http://rubular.com).
Permite probar directamente el string en cuestión.
Saludos

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes que nada, al manipular HTML, deberías utilizar las herramientas diseñadas para eso. La forma correcta de hacerlo es utilizando el [DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/hf9hbf87(v=vs.110).aspx). Un cambio en el código HTML, incluso si es mínimo, haría que una expresión regular falle. Te recomiendo evitar el uso de regex para esto, y sólo pensaría en usar lo que respondo abajo en casos en los que se esté totalmente seguro que el HTML sigue un formato fijo y no variará.

---

> El problema es que en expresiones regulares la negación debe ir dentro de corchetes.

Eso no es correcto. Los corchetes se usan para coincidir con una clase de caracteres (incluso cuando está negada con un `^`), que coinciden con un solo caracter.

Para buscar coincidencias que no estén seguidas por un patrón, se usan [inspecciones negativas](http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html) (*[negative lookaheads](http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html)*).
La sintaxis es `(?!patrón)`, que se podría traducir cómo "*no está seguido por*". Es decir, intenta coincidir con el *patrón* y, si coincide, el intento actual **falla**. Estas inspecciones no consumen caracteres luego de ser intentadas (se vuelve a la posición en la que se estaba antes de la inspección).

---

> Mi idea es, para que no coja un `src` que no le corresponda, encontrar la cadena que empiece en `<a href` y acabe en `</a>` siempre y cuando no haya ningún `</a` ya dentro en ella. De esta forma me aseguro que los posibles patrones que le ponga no coja más código del que deba.

**RegEx**:

```regex
(<a href\s*=\s*")[^"]*("[^<]*(?:<(?!\/a\b)[^<]*)*?<img\b[^>]*? src\s*=\s*"([^"]*)")
```

**Reemplazo**:

```
$1$3$2
```

**Descripción**:

- `(<a href\s*=\s*")` - Grupo 1 (captura en `$1`)
  Coincide con el texto literal `<a href="` (con espacios opcionales alrededor del igual).
- `[^"]*` - Cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean comillas (el contenido del `href`).
- `("[^<]*(?:<(?!\/a\b)[^<]*)*?<img\b[^>]*? src\s*=\s*"([^"]*)")` - Grupo 2 (captura en `$2`).

  - `"[^<]*` - las comillas que cierran el `src` seguidas de cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean `<`.
  - `(?:<(?!\/a\b)[^<]*)*?` - y opcionalmente (cuantos menos sea posible) un `<`, siempre que no esté seguido de `/a` (**acá es donde usamos un *negative lookahead***), luego seguido de más caracteres que no sean un `<`.
  - `<img\b[^>]*?` - el texto literal `<img` seguido de caracteres que no sean `>` (seguimos dentro del tag *img*).
  - `src\s*=\s*"` - el texto literal `src="` (con espacios opcionales alrededor del igual).
  - `([^"]*)` - Grupo 3 (captura en `$3`).
    Cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean comillas (el contenido del `src`).
  - `"` - las comillas que cierran el `src`.

Al reemplazar por `$1$3$2` estamos reemplazando por: el inicio de la etiqueta `a` hasta las comillas que abren el `href` (**$1**) **+** el contenido del `src`  (**$3**) **+** el resto, desde las comillas que cierran el `href` en adelante  (**$2**).

**Consideraciones**:

La expresión regular fue escrita para cumplir con los casos mostrados en la pregunta. Si bien cubren correctamente la sintaxis esperada, como se comentó al principio, siempre habrá excepciones que la hagan fallar.
Entre ellas: *si hay 2 imágenes dentro de la misma etiqueta `a`, sólo toma la primera con la que coincide; si hay unas comillas escapadas dentro de alguna URL (aunque no debería haber), las toma como que se cierra ahí; si hay algún parámetro dentro de la etiqueta `img` cuyo valor termine en `src=` lo tomaría erróneamente*; son algunas de las que se me ocurren para ejemplificar, pero hay más.

**Código**:

```asp
<%
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Global = True
textoHTML = "<a href=""imagen1.jpg""><img src=""imagen1.jpg"" />Salto 1</a>"
regEx.Pattern = "(<a href\s*=\s*"")[^""]*(""[^<]*(?:<(?!\/a\b)[^<]*)*?<img\b[^>]*? src\s*=\s*""([^""]*)"")"
reemplazo = "$1$3$2"
Response.Write regEx.Replace( textoHTML, reemplazo)
%>
```

**Resultado**:

```html
<a href="imagen1.jpg"><img src="imagen1.jpg" />Salto 1</a>
```

**Demo**:

https://www.myregextester.com/?r=bf0a0b25

Comment: Lo de "negative lookaheads" lo desconocía totalmente. Si no desde luego ese es el camino para tirar. De 10!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por abrirme tantas ventanas :D. Lo de manipular el DOM sería genial. Ojeando ya detenidamente hay librerías pasa vbscript que permiten manipular XML, claro... :) Intentaremos ver esta opción también.

Comment: Creo que cómo usar DOM sería una pregunta nueva, y hay diversas formas (y no recuerdo cuál sería más práctica hoy en día en ASP). Un ejemplo podría ser [Parsing XML with ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20411840/5290909)

Comment: Hola. Si de algo sirve, siempre uso [regexr](http://regexr.com) y [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com) para visualizar y probar expresiones regulares.

Comment: @ArieCwHat ninguna de esas utiliza el motor que usa ASP... Podrás encontrar más herramientas en la descripción de la etiqueta [regex](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)